# Change of airport in Tokyo

Tags: visas

I am an Indian passport holder, I am travelling to Kitakyushu and plan is MAA-CMB-NRT-KKJ. I have a valid Japanese visa , but my port of entry is Kitakyushu (KKJ). I need to change airports in Tokyo from Narita (NRT) to Haneda (HND). Will there by problem with this? Will I be in need of any transit visa apart from the visa what I have for the change of airport in Tokyo?

Comment: Is a port of entry specified on your visa, or do you mean you wrote Kitakyushu in the "port of entry" field on your visa application?

Answer (score 4):

Since Haneda to Kitakyushu is a domestic flight, **your port of entry will be Narita**, where you will need to go through immigration before you can proceed to Haneda.

However, as far as I'm aware, Japanese visas don't usually indicate a port of entry or restrict you to one.  So it should be fine to enter at Narita and then continue on a domestic flight, even if you originally mistakenly stated Kitakyushu as your port of entry when applying for the visa.